# How can I debug istio JWT authentication?

Tags: istio

I have successfully deployed a Policy for JWT authentication and it is indeed returning 401 for missing tokens on the path I've included. But for valid tokens it still returns a 401. I have created the JWKS endpoint and matched up the issuer. I also confirmed the tokens work with the keys from the jwks endpoint outside the cluster.

I just have no visibility into why it might be failing. I have tried the envoy (istio-proxy) logs, but they are just basic access logs. I can see the 401 there, but no more details around what was attempted and why it failed to verify the token.

What else can I do to debug this?

Comment: Hi, what version of istio are You using? What method did You use to get the logs? Did You enable Envoy's access logging?

Comment: Using 1.4, used kubctl logs on both pilot pod and envoy proxy container pod. Yes, envoy access logging enabled.

Comment: Can you share Your `Policy` yaml? Verify if the `issuer` is reachable if its outside the cluster.